# Wordpress: wp_get_current_user returning blank keys only

Tags: wordpress

I am facing an issue while fetching info by using wordpress default function wp_get_current_user(). It is returning only array with keys but not values. Here is the array output and my code.

Output:

```
WP_User Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( ) [ID] => 0 [caps] => Array ( ) [cap_key] => [roles] => Array ( ) [allcaps] => Array ( ) [filter] => )
```

My code:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
print_r($current_user);
```

**Note:** I am logged in as a subscriber role.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What actually want to get information of user by this function.

Comment: yes i want user info and user role too. Thanks for your reply

Comment: You can use get_userdata(get_current_user_id()) function to get all information.

Comment: [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163407/get-current-user-id-returns-0) is a discussion on similary issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code to get information of logged in user

```
global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
  echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
  echo 'User level: ' . $current_user->user_level . "\n";
  echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
  echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
  echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
  echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
```

to get current user role use this code

```
 if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user = new WP_User($user_ID);
        if (!empty($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
            foreach ($user->roles as $role)
                echo $role;
        }
    }
```

and many more attribute of current user.

Comment: global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();echo $current_user->user_email;  Still not showing the result.